# Lubridate filter for month and hour in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I've been trying to figure out how to use the lubridate & tidyverse package to filter for a specific hour (2pm) in my dataset within the subset of the month of January. The dataset itself has 4 years of meteorological data and I'm trying to find the mean daily AirTemp at 2pm in January for the 4 years

my data currently looks like this:

**Data**

```
structure(list(Timestamp = c("2010-01-01 01:00:00", "2010-01-01 02:00:00", 
"2010-01-01 03:00:00", "2010-01-01 04:00:00", "2010-01-01 05:00:00", 
"2010-01-01 06:00:00"), Temp = c(44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 43L, 42L
), Humid = c(100L, 96L, 93L, 89L, 89L, 83L), Precip = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"))

            Timestamp    Temp    Humid      Precip 
1 2010-01-01 01:00:00      44      100           0 
2 2010-01-01 02:00:00      44       96           0 
3 2010-01-01 03:00:00      44       93           0 
4 2010-01-01 04:00:00      44       89           0 
5 2010-01-01 05:00:00      43       89           0 
6 2010-01-01 06:00:00      42       83           0
```

I've tried writing my filters so many time but there seems to be a misunderstanding in the way I'm writing my syntax I think

e.g.

```
weather %>% 
mutate(gethour = hour(weather$Timestamp)) %>% 
filter(gethour == gethour("2:00 PM"))
```

every time I try to write a simple filter I get errors, does anyone know what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get data for 2pm in the month of January for all years you can use :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

weather %>% filter(hour(Timestamp) == 14 & month(Timestamp) == 1)
```

Similarly in base R, we can use `subset` :

```
subset(weather,format(Timestamp, "%H") == "14" & format(Timestamp,, "%m") == "01")
```

Comment: That works brilliantly, and a lot more simple than what I thought was possible, thanks Ronak! I'm still learning R and this helped a lot!